# Compiler complains make_shared() expects l-value

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, make-shared

I have a simple class.  One of its constructors takes two `int` values as arguments:

simple_class.h

```
class SimpleClass {
   private:
      int d_ii;
      int d_jj;
   public:
      SimpleClass() : d_ii(40), d_jj(10) {}
      SimpleClass( const int ii, const int jj ) : d_ii(ii), d_jj(jj) {}
};
```

test.t.cpp

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
//
//  Test Program
#include <memory>
#include <simple_class.h>

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   SimpleClass sc1;
   SimpleClass sc2( 10, 20 );

   std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc1( new SimpleClass(10,12) );

   int ii = 10;
   int jj = 16;
   std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc2 = std::make_shared<SimpleClass> ( ii, jj );

   std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc3 = std::make_shared<SimpleClass> ( 10, 16 );

   return 0;
}
```

Running on a macbook.  Here is my compile statement:

> gcc -o test -I. test.t.cpp -lstdc++

But it produces this error:

```
test.t.cpp:18:41: error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'
 std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc3 = std::make_shared<SimpleClass> ( 10, 16 );
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4708:1: note:
      candidate function [with _Tp = SimpleClass, _A0 = int, _A1 = int] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st
      argument
make_shared(_A0& __a0, _A1& __a1)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4692:1: note:
      candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
make_shared()
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4700:1: note:
      candidate function template not viable: requires single argument '__a0', but 2 arguments were provided
make_shared(_A0& __a0)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4716:1: note:
      candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
make_shared(_A0& __a0, _A1& __a1, _A2& __a2)
^
1 error generated.
```

So my question is, why doesn't this usage of `make_shared()` work?

```
std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc2 = std::make_shared<SimpleClass>( 10, 16 );
```

Notice that the version with the l-values passed *does* compile:

```
   int ii = 10;
   int jj = 16;
   std::shared_ptr<SimpleClass> spSc2 = std::make_shared<SimpleClass> ( ii, jj );
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

My constructor declares the arguments as `const` (although that should not be necessary).  And the [examples given here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/) pass constants to `make_shared()`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d582117f25211a0d)

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Dino@MacDino:~/code/test$ gcc -v

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: You are using a very old version of gcc.  experimental support really started in version 4.3.  I really suggest you update and try again.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling C++ code with a C compiler, use `g++` instead. Also, `std::shared_ptr` and relatives are C++11 features, which need to be enabled on G++ compiler. So your command line would be `g++ -o test -I. test.t.cpp -std=c++11` (it is not needed to link against libstdc++, g++ does it automatically)

**edit:**
Also, G++ 4.2 does not support C++11 features. On OSX, use `clang++` instead

Comment: If he was compiling with a C compiler there would be a lot more errors.  `class` and `std::shared_ptr` would also be errors.

Comment: Yeah, it's the lack of C++11 support that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks.   I notice that
> gcc -o test -I. test.t.cpp -lstdc++ -std=c++11
also works.

Comment: please note that g++ 4.2 does not support C++11. use clang/clang++

Comment: My understanding is that g++ is exactly the same as "gcc -lstdc++" (which explains why adding -std=c++11 to my gcc compile line worked ok).

Comment: What I don't understand is this:  I thought shared_ptr and make_shared are c++11.  If so, then why did they compile at all before I added -std=c++11 ??

Comment: Not sure how Apple's GCC works, but it seems that it uses `std::tr1::shared_ptr` automatically (see http://cafbit.com/entry/cplusplus_11_features ), dropping the need for the namespace `tr1`. And C++ TR1 did not support `std::make_shared`, which was introduced with C++11.